# How to find the path to blob?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to export a machine learning model I created in Azure Machine Learning studio. One of the required input is "Path to blob beginning with container"

[image: Here is the screenshoot from azure export]

How do I find this path? I have already created a blob storage but I have no idea how to find the path to the blob storage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should be able to find this from the Azure portal. Open the storage account, drill down into blobs, then your container. Use properties for the context menu, the URL should be the path ?

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! The inconsistency in naming had confused me

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this URL using [**Azure Storage Explorer(on-prem)**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/storage-explorer/) Software.

Also through an Online version of [**Azure Storage Explorer**](https://azurestorage.azurewebsites.net)

You can also simply guess the URL if you know the `storage account name` and `container name`

https://[storageaccount].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[blob]